# Битрикс24. Последовательное создание/выполнение задач в зависимости от стадии выполнения сделки. Бизнес процесс, роботы, задачи, стадии сделки

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Сделка проходит стадии, в одной стадии может быть несколько задач. Некоторые задачи может выполнять только один сотрудник, некоторые кто то из нескольких. Когда завершается одна задача, создается следующая и отправляется сотруднику/сотрудникам. Если группа сотрудников может выполнять задачу, то отправляется всем из тех кто может выполнять, остальным не отправляется. По завершении выполнения задачи, должна создаваться следующая задача и сделка должна переходить на следующую стадию.

С битриксом (облачный) начал знакомиться совсем недавно, пока что смутно представляю, как это делается.

**Вопрос №1:** Правильно ли я понимаю, что это делается с помощью бизнес процессов - создается блок схема, отслеживающая выполнение задач и создающая задачи, переключающая стадии сделки?

**Вопрос №2:** И/или может быть для этого надо задействовать роботов и RPA? Триггеры срабатывают в зависимости от действий клиентов и поэтому в данном контексте они применяться не должны, если задача не связана с почтой, звонком и т.п., исходящими от клиента?

Мною был найден следующий шаблон бизнес процессов: ["Шаблон бизнес-процесса для последовательного создания задач. Задачи должны создаваться одна за другой, при том что каждая последующая задача должна создаваться только после того, как предыдущий пользователь закончит выполнение своей задачи. Бизнес-процесс включает работу с действием PHP код."](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=57&LESSON_ID=7125)

И статья: ["Как создать последовательные задачи разным пользователем (для коробочной версии)"](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/5474089/#section94971)

**Вопрос №3:** В материалах по ссылкам требуется выполнение PHP кода для выбора пользователя из массива, содержащего список сотрудников. Правильно ли я понял, что это необходимо только для того что бы распределять задачи по одному сотруднику на задачу из массива имен сотрудников? А если достаточно одну и ту же задачу создать сразу для нескольких сотрудников, то этот PHP и не нужен вовсе в моем случае?

**Вопрос №4:** откуда и как может запускаться бизнес процесс (если я правильно понял, что моя задача решается с помощью бизнес процесса)? Правильно ли я понимаю, что бизнес процесс лучше всего запускать с помощью робота, который включится в дело как только будет создана сделка и установится в самую первую стадию? Дальше уже роботы не понадобятся и бизнес процесс сам начнет создавать новые задачи для сотрудников по блок-схеме, ожидать выполнения и переключать сделку на новые стадии?

**Вопрос №5:** как примерно будет выглядеть блок-схема? Элемент "Выбор сотрудника" (группы сотрудников, для которых будет создаваться задача) -> Элемент "Задача" -> После выполнения задачи, должен следовать отдельный элемент блок схемы, который в случае надобности выполнения контроля, отправит выполненную задачу на проверку? -> Дальше очередной элемент "Выбор сотрудника" (или нескольких) и после него очередной элемент "Задача", а далее элемент выполняющий отправку выполненной задачи проверяющему и т.д.?

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос №1: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это делается с помощью бизнес процессов - создается блок схема, отслеживающая выполнение задач и создающая задачи, переключающая стадии сделки?

В целом да. Но тут есть три варианта:

1. Последовательный бизнес-процесс. Самый простой вариант в создании, но самый неудобный при поддержке и внесении изменений.
2. Бизнес-процесс на статусах. Чуть более сложный вариант, но сохраняется необходимость проверять статус сделки и статус процесса.
3. Настройка роботов на статусах через дизайнер бизнес-процессов. Самый оптимальный вариант.

> Вопрос №2: И/или может быть для этого надо задействовать роботов и RPA? Триггеры срабатывают в зависимости от действий клиентов и поэтому в данном контексте они применяться не должны, если задача не связана с почтой, звонком и т.п., исходящими от клиента?

Для вашего случая лучше всего подходит именно дизайнер БП.

> Вопрос №3: В материалах по ссылкам требуется выполнение PHP кода для выбора пользователя из массива, содержащего список сотрудников. Правильно ли я понял, что это необходимо только для того что бы распределять задачи по одному сотруднику на задачу из массива имен сотрудников? А если достаточно одну и ту же задачу создать сразу для нескольких сотрудников, то этот PHP и не нужен вовсе в моем случае?

То что вы нашли насколько я помню там идет перебор. И это уже неактуально т.к. сейчас есть активити "Итератор". В вашем случае если одинаковую задачу надо поставить нескольким сотрудникам, то этот список надо внеси в переменную БП (лучше всего если это хранится в константе, а когда нужно значения передаются в переменную), а затем итератором перебирается переменная и внутри итератора ставится задача.

> Вопрос №4: откуда и как может запускаться бизнес процесс (если я правильно понял, что моя задача решается с помощью бизнес процесса)? Правильно ли я понимаю, что бизнес процесс лучше всего запускать с помощью робота, который включится в дело как только будет создана сделка и установится в самую первую стадию? Дальше уже роботы не понадобятся и бизнес процесс сам начнет создавать новые задачи для сотрудников по блок-схеме, ожидать выполнения и переключать сделку на новые стадии?

Под роботами есть строка "Редактировать в дизайнере бизнес-процессов" - рекомендую использовать такой вариант. Так вы на каждой стадии сделаете свой отдельный процесс.

> Вопрос №5: как примерно будет выглядеть блок-схема? Элемент "Выбор сотрудника" (группы сотрудников, для которых будет создаваться задача) -> Элемент "Задача" -> После выполнения задачи, должен следовать отдельный элемент блок схемы, который в случае надобности выполнения контроля, отправит выполненную задачу на проверку? -> Дальше очередной элемент "Выбор сотрудника" (или нескольких) и после него очередной элемент "Задача", а далее элемент выполняющий отправку выполненной задачи проверяющему и т.д.?

Если задача на одного пользователя ставится всегда, то он указывается в активити которое ставит задачу, а лучше из отдельной константы. Т.к. пользователи имеют свойство увольняться и надо их заменять.

Если на нескольких, то задача ставится в активити "Итератор". Прием задачи - это опция "Требует контроля..." или как-то так. Выставляется в активити "Задача". В этом случае после того как ответственный завершает задачу она уходит на контроль Постановщику у которого 2 кнопки "Принять" и "Вернуть на доработку". В активити задача также поставьте опцию "Ожидать завершения задачи". Чтобы процесс не шел дальше пока задача не будет успешно принята постановщиком.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, БП уже написал, теперь возник другой вопрос - если организация меняет тариф облачного битрикса на тот в котором нет БП, то в каких случаях перенос функционала БП в php обработчик и вебхуки окажется невозможным? Или в общем нет того что нельзя будет сделать через rest и вебхуки, что делается через БП?

Comment: php-обработчик только в коробочной версии.
придется мудрить с веб-хуками.
если в облачном битрикс24 нет бизнес-процессы, то все что они делают не будет работать.

Comment: да, имел ввиду вебхуки в обработчик на отдельном сервере будут данные отправлять - такое мудрение имеет смысл или неоправданно сложно и не факт что удастся весь функционал БП на них реализовать?

Comment: Вполне себе выход.